# How do I exclude specific subclasses from a class type?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class Guardian {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
    /* ... */
}

class Father extends Guardian {
    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }
    /* ... */
}

class Mother extends Guardian {
    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }
    /* ... */
}

class GrandParent extends Guardian {
    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }
    /* ... */
}

function parentFunc(parent: Guardian) {
    /* ... */
}


parentFunc(new Father('Kyle'));
parentFunc(new Mother('Theresa'));
// how do I make this error without explicitly saying parent must be Father | Mother
parent(new GrandParent('Jace'));
```

In the `parentFunc()` function, I want the `parent` paremeter to be of type `Guardian` but NOT of type `GrandParent`. Is there a way to do this? The reason is that I have several subclasses of some parent class A, and there's a function I want to accept all subclass types except a few particular ones. It would be much cleaner to just exclude those subclasses specifically without using a large union expression.

I've tried doing something like

```
parentFunc(parent: Exclude<Guardian, GrandParent>) {/* ... */}
```

but that doesn't work. I've also tried Googling the solution, but I can't figure out how to phrase it because I don't get any relevant results.

**Edit:**

To add further context, this involves a custom element made by extending `HTMLElement`. Take the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="regular-elem">HELLO</div>
<cool-par class="cool-par"></cool-par>
```

**TS**

```
export class CoolPar extends HTMLElement {
  bgColor = 'black';
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

    const htmlString = `
      <style>
        :host {
          font-size: 20px;
        }
        
        .container {
          background-color: ${this.bgColor};
          width: fit-content;
        }
        
        .paragraph {
          color: white;
        }
      </style>

      <div class="container">
        <p class="paragraph">WORLD</p>
      </div>
    `;

    const template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = htmlString;
    const element = template.content.cloneNode(true);
    shadow.append(element);
  }
}

customElements.define('cool-par', CoolPar);

// should NOT allow CoolPar
function elemFunc(elem: Element | null) {
  if (!elem) { throw Error('Target element not found'); }
  console.log(elem);
}

elemFunc(document.querySelector('.regular-elem') as HTMLElement);
elemFunc(document.querySelector('.cool-par') as CoolPar); // should have TS error
```

Comment: Are there any properties that exist on Mother and Father, but which don't exist on Grandparent? Or which have a different type?

Comment: While possible, [the real solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is probably to not use inheritance here. The entire point of it is that any subclass should be a valid representation of its ancestor. Yet in your hierarchy that's not true.  It's hard to say what the exact correct solution is but consider using composition

Comment: • Please [edit] to provide a [mre] without [completely empty classes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely), otherwise it's hard to demonstrate what you're looking for. • You can add a property to `GrandParent` which is expected to be absent elsewhere, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NV5EMw) but I don't know if that works for you (especially without a [mre] as mentioned before)

Comment: I added some more context to my question. The reason I'm using inheritance is because I'm extending HTMLElement and creating a custom element, and there are some functions that I do not want to allow the custom element in. (Sorry I didn't add this before—I didn't think the specifics would be relevant)

Comment: Is `CoolPar` supposed to be one of the other classes? I'd love to see a [mre] where the issue jumps out at me. Otherwise I still just suggest [this version of your code](https://tsplay.dev/NV5EMw); could you respond to say whether or not that's what you're looking for?

Comment: @jcalz That's my bad—I didn't see the change you made in the code you provided. Yes that works. In the code I added to my post edit then, I could add a field like `isCoolPar` to the `CoolPar` class (which of course no other `Element` would have) and then have the `elem` parameter in `elemFunc()` be `(Element & {isCoolPar?: never}) | null`.

Comment: More like `{isCoolPar?: never}` since you're not going to have a `never` property, but yes. I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.